# KSQLDB Rest API: return query results as json

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I'm issuing the following request:

```
curl --http2 -X "POST" "http://localhost:8088/query-stream"
             -H "Content-Type: application/vnd.ksql.v1+json; charset=utf-8"
             -d $'{
                  "sql": "SELECT * FROM USERS EMIT CHANGES;",
                  "streamsProperties": {
                    "ksql.streams.auto.offset.reset": "earliest"
                  }
}
```

The result I'm getting is:

```
{"queryId":"cdfb3ccc-0ab5-4186-a249-b279bfc09587","columnNames":["USERID","NAME"],"columnTypes":["STRING","STRING"]}
["1","Max"]
["2","Alex"]
["13","Andrew"]
...
```

Is there a way I could get the data in json format?

```
{"userid":"1","name":"Max"}
{"userid":"2","name":"Alex"}
{"userid":"13","name":"Andrew"}
```

It is easier to deserialize this data into POCO objects if they are in json than to parse the 'row' format.

Answer (score 3):

Per [the docs](https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/developer-guide/ksqldb-rest-api/streaming-endpoint/) you can set the `Accept` header. It defaults to `application/vnd.ksqlapi.delimited.v1` but can also be set to `application/json`:

```
curl --show-error --silent \
         -H "application/vnd.ksqlapi.delimited.v1" \
         --http2 'http://localhost:8088/query-stream' \
         --data-raw '{"sql":"SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS WHERE ID=42;"}'
{"queryId":null,"columnNames":["ID","FIRST_NAME","LAST_NAME","EMAIL","GENDER","COMMENTS"],"columnTypes":["INTEGER","STRING","STRING","STRING","STRING","STRING"]}
[42,"Rick","Astley","r.astley@example.com","Male",""]
```

```
curl --show-error --silent \
         -H "Accept:application/json" \
         --http2 'http://localhost:8088/query-stream' \
         --data-raw '{"sql":"SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS WHERE ID=42;"}'
[{"queryId":null,"columnNames":["ID","FIRST_NAME","LAST_NAME","EMAIL","GENDER","COMMENTS"],"columnTypes":["INTEGER","STRING","STRING","STRING","STRING","STRING"]},[42,"Rick","Astley","r.astley@example.com","Male",""]]
```

Comment: Thanks, Robin, however that's not exactly what I was looking for. I need a push KSQL Rest API query that would return my records as JSON objects, not the CSV like style. Following your example, although you make a pull query (with single returned result), I would like to get every record in the format: {
 "id": 42,
 "first_name:"Rick",
 "last_name:":"Astley",
 "email": "r.astley@example.com",
 "gender": "Male",
 "comments": ""
}

Another point, is when I issue a push query (with 'EMIT CHANGES') with -H 'Accept:application/json' - I don't get any result.

Comment: I see - yes that's not quite what's available currently. Feel free to comment/upvote on https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/issues/3526.